# Question About equal signs in Theorems

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Lets say for example, $L$ is a linear mapping with $V$ as its domain and $W$ as its co-domain.

**Theorem:** $L(0) = 0$. (Zero vectors)

I know its wrong to assume that every zero vector in $W$ is mapped from a zero vector in $V$, but I can't logically explain why!

Since $L(0) = 0$, and equal signs go both ways (double implication), isn't the statement $L(0) = 0$ implying the $0$ vector in $V$ only maps to the zero vector in $W$, and the zero vector in $W$ can be only mapped from the zero vector in $V$?

I know this is wrong. Can someone explain why?

Thanks

Comment: There's only one zero vector.

Comment: sorry i edited the question

Comment: The formula just states a fact, not an implication. Are you perhaps worried about $2+3=5$  implying that if the sum of two numbers is $5$, then the two numbers must be $2$ and $3$? I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with an example.  Let $A$ be a linear map from $$A:R^2 \to R$$ defined as $A(x,y)=x$.
$$$$  Now clearly $A(0,0)=0$, but $A(0,1)=0$ and $(0,1) \not= (0,0)$.  Now using the definition of the linear map $$0=1-1=A(1,x)-A(1,y)=A((1-1),x-y)=A(0,x-y)$$ if $x\not=y$ then the zero vector in $R$ does not map only to the zero vector in $R^2$.  Now the above example shows why "the zero vector in W can be only mapped from the zero vector in V" is incorrect.  If you understand what the linear map is doing you can see that in fact the entire $y-axis$ in $R^2$ can be mapped to zero in $R$ by setting $x=0$ in $(x,y)$.  $$$$  In the two seperate spaces $V$ and $W$ the zero elements are unique respectively.  Now the zero vector in $V$ may not be the only element in $V$ that maps to the zero vector in $W$.  You will need more info about the linear map $L$ (one to one, onto, etc.) to determine whether the zero vector in V is the only element in V that maps to the zero vector in W.

Answer (score 0):

$L(0)=0$ indeed means that $0$ maps to $0$ by the linear transform $L$.

But this doesn't tell you anything about $L(v)$ for other $v$, which might be such that $L(v)=0$ ($L$ might be non-invertible).

Comment: Indeed. We could have $L(v)=0 \space \forall v \in V$.

Comment: So this could mean that L(v) = 0  where v does not equal 0, or v = 0 where L(v) != 0?

Comment: @TimWeah: no, there is no doubt.

Comment: But if it could also mean that v = 0  where L(v) != 0, what is the point of that Theorem?

Comment: @TimWeah: be serious. How do you want to have $L(0)\ne0$ when $L(0)=0$ ?

Comment: But thats the whole point of my question. So the statement L(0) = 0 is essentially a one way implication, instead of it being a double implication.

Comment: What I mean by this is that: Consider L(x) = y. The theorem states that if x = 0, then y = 0, but no the other way around (if y = 0, then x = 0)

Comment: @TimWeah: and what bothers you in that ?

Comment: Sorry I guess I got carried away from the question. I thought the "equal signs" always meant double implications, but in this case, its a single implication. Thats what I'm confused about.

Comment: @TimWeah: there are no "implications". Just two values being the same.

Answer (score 0):

The equal sign goes both ways in the sense that $L(0) = 0$ is saying that the vectors $L(0)$ and $0$ are the same vectors in $W$.

If you are trying to view it as an implication, it is indeed a one-way implication saying that "if $v = 0$ then $L(v) = 0$." It **does not mean** however that the zero vector in $V$ is the only vector $v$ for which $L(v)=0$.  To say that we would need to say that "$L(v) = 0$ if and only if $v=0$", or that "$0 \in V$ is the preimage of $0 \in W$ under $L$".